# Sort taxonomy page alphabetically by meta rather than default post date

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta, sort

The user starts at a page showing posts of custom post type, "agent".

Each post displayed shows a region/custom taxonomy it belongs to and links to a page that shows all posts in the region the user clicked.

This is how these posts are currently displayed,

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Ideally I'd like to to sort these alphabetically by meta_key lname rather than by post date which appears to be the wordpress default.

Thanks for any input

Edit: Script I use to get all custom post type Agents. Puts one specified post as last post.

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'agents',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'lname',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(array( 'key' => 'lname' )),
        'post__not_in' => array( '93' ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    $loop2 = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'agents',
        'post__in' => array( '93' ) ) );
?>
<?php
    if($loop->have_posts() || $loop2->have_posts()) { 
    if($loop->have_posts()) { while($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working.

```
global $wp_query;   

query_posts(array_merge(array('orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'rw_lname' ),$wp_query->query));

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this before the loop:

```
<?php
query_posts( wp_parse_args( $query_string, array(
    'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
    ) ) );
?>
```

Comment: when I try your code it doesn't show any posts anymore

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as the above to answers, but using `meta_query` instead of `meta_key`. `meta_key` was deprecated as of WP 3.1.  I'm not sure if ordering by `meta_value` still works in this case, however.

```
$wpse20766args = array(
     'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
     'order'    => 'ASC',
     'post_type'    => 'agent',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'meta_query'   => array(
        array( 
            'key' => 'lname'
        )
     ) 
);

$wpse20766q = new WP_Query( $wpse20766args );

// then the loop...
if( $wpse20766q->have_posts() ):
while( $wpse20766q->have_posts() ) :
$wpse20766q->the_post(); 

// do stuff...

endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Well, it sorts now, but it doesn't appear to affect posts by admins, they are at the top, and it isn't showing just the region/taxonomy that I click, it shows all regions/taxonomies.

Comment: You're going to have to do a similar thing to create pages for taxonomies.  you'll need a taxonomy-your_custom_tax_name.php file, then sort those by meta_value.  

What do you mean it doesn't effect posts by admins?  Is their lname field set to 'admin'?

Comment: In my previous comment I was using the code you posted above in my taxonomy-regions.php. Not sure about the admin issue, my agents custom post type has a meta field for lname, I use nearly identical code as what you posted for the page which lists all agents and it doesn't seperate posts of admins from authors, see edit above for this code I use to search for all agents posts.

Comment: Get rid of admins by adding an `'author' => -1` (replace -1 with -[your admins user ID]) to the query.